# What's wrong with the smarty arithmetic I did?

Tags: math, smarty, arithmetic-expressions, smarty2

Following is the smarty arithmetic code I tried but it's not working:

```
{if $cur_page == 1} {assign var='i' value=1} {else} {assign var='i' value=$cur_page * 15  + 1} {/if}
```

Can someone please correct my code? If you want any other information regarding the issue please do let me know.

Comment: "Not working" is not an acceptable description of a problem.

Comment: @GregS : It's giving smarty syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply won't work in Smarty2. In Smarty3 this code will work without a problem.

In Smarty2 you should use **[math()](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.math.tpl)** function to achieve the same so the working code in Smarty2 for that would be:

```
{if $cur_page == 1}
    {assign var='i' value=1}
{else}
    {math equation="x* 15 + 1" x=$cur_page assign='i'}
{/if}
```